# SQL error on ubuntu command line

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu, command

I am working with a SQL database on a Ubuntu LAMP server.  I am attempting to create a new database then a new table in it, which can hold `blob`s.  I can login, create my database, use it, but then I cannot create the table.  I am doing:

```
$mysql -u root -p mypass
mysql> use frame;
Database changed
mysql> create table 'frame_info' ( 'frame_data' BLOB NOT NULL, 'frame_name' VARCHAR(45) NULL, 'creator_name' VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('frame_data'));
```

From there, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near ''fram
e_info' ( create table 'frame_info' ( 'frame_data' BLOB NOT NULL, 'frame_na' at 
line 1
```

Obviously that error is truncated by the `mysql` display, but you get the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use backticks `` ` `` instead of single quotes `'` or (in your case) you can succeed without them at all :

```
 create table `frame_info` (
     `frame_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
     `frame_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
     `creator_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`frame_data`)
 );
```

Comment: Fantastic! I should have caught that.  Thanks a ton!